# After TrueType fonts intstallation, they are not availabe on openoffice

Tags: openoffice.org

Every tutorial or instructions for the installation of fonts like Arial, Times and so on in Openoffice, say I have to install the »TrueType« fonts.

Altough Synaptic says I have the fonts installed, they don't appear in the list of available fonts in openwriter.

These are, for instance, all the fonts I get with initial **a** (there should be `arial`).

[image]

Is there something I'm missing in order to have access to those fonts? I'm on Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and/or `fonts-liberation` packages in Synaptics. They provide Microsoft TrueType fonts and substitutes respectively.

Comment: I have both installed.